# How to remove duplicated values on Mongodb by date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have two collections that I want to merge. After merging, I need to remove duplicated values, keeping the newest document and removing older ones.

I have tried to get that done by the aggregate method:

```
self.collection.aggregate([
    {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'algoritmo_result',
            'localField': 'slug',
            'foreignField': 'slug',
            'as': 'copies_result'
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$swab', 'count': {'$sum': 1}
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {
            'obs': {'$not': ignore_string},
            'count': 1
        },
    }
])
```

The problem is that I am removing every duplicated value and not just older values.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that i've found for that was to make a filter that searches in the current collection for the last duplicated document and compare the slug (unique field, could also be _id) of both objects.

It looks like this:

```
    def last_duplicated_patient(self, swab):
        return self.collection.find({'swab': swab}).sort([("_id", pymongo.DESCENDING)]).limit(1)

    def aggregate_result_collection(self):
        ignore_string = re.compile('coleta', re.IGNORECASE)
        patients_with_results = list(self.collection.aggregate([
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': 'algoritmo_result',
                    'localField': 'slug',
                    'foreignField': 'slug',
                    'as': 'copies_result'
                }
            },
            {
                '$match': {
                    'obs': {'$not': ignore_string},
                },
            },
        ]))
        patients_with_results = list(filter(
            lambda x: x.get('slug') == list(self.last_duplicated_patient(x.get('swab')))[0].get('slug'),
            patients_with_results
        ))
```